# How would I play a video in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, video

I am trying to make a program that makes a JFrame window open with an MP4 video, it can be any video type like avi and such. I was trying to make a gif loop with music playing but for the life of me, I cant convert the video to a gif without it having really bad FPS. So if possible how do I put a video inside a JFrame. Basically I just need a way to make a window open with the video looping with the sound playing too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [JavaFx Media](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm#JFXMD101).